# Is it not clear - Are WhatsApp API alive? Can I use it?

Tags: whatsapp

I don't understand using Google if WhatsApp API are alive, and how to use it. No documentation, no links, no tutorials. Only articles about "WhatsAPP API won't be public".

What's the truth?

Comment: when you're having trouble finding documentation of a supposed api for a very popular and active platform, that might be a very good indication that it *isn't there at all*

Comment: It sounds like you can't use it, because it's not public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight answer to your question is, there is no publicly available WhatsApp API. It is because `WhatsApp Inc` does not offer its propriety instant messenger as open-source.

But if you are really interested you can check `Yowsup library` or'WhatsApp-purple' and another reverse engineered library available in [GIT](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI)

Hope its helpful for you

Comment: Of course the existence of an API and whether a product is open-source are orthogonal issues...

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there are a lot of WhatsApp API providers as official and illegal.

Official providers (known as Business API partners) can be found here  https://www.facebook.com/business/partner-directory/search?solution_type=messaging&platforms=whatsapp

Regarding unnoficial WhatsApp API there is no single spot website to find them all. But one guy try to collect and actualize info about them on github  https://github.com/yredsmih/whatsapp-blacklisted-providers